# How to properly parse a buffer in elisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp

What is the correct way to parse a buffer in order to store its content and reuse it?

Say I got this buffer:

```
always|five|words|by|line
not|always|the|same|words
sometimes|no|lines|at|all
but|only|five|no|more/less
```

What would be the best approach to construct a list from the symbols found in the lines (and error nicely if none are found)?

The buffer is there, I can visit it, get its content like so

```
(message "Buffer content : %s" (buffer-substring (point-min) (point-max)))
```

after I killed it cleanly, but somehow I fail at constructing the object (a list "lines" of lists "words") that would allow me to do this :

```
(list-length lines)
    ==> 4

(car (nthcdr 3 lines))
    ==> sometimes
```

Can a kindred soul point me toward the light? Thank you for your patience, Lisp elders.

Comment: I think I got a way to count the lines. But as to the storing of the words in easily retrievable form, no luck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could also use the built-in `split-string` function, similar to `split` in Perl and other languages:

```
(defun buffer-to-list-of-lists (buf)
  (with-current-buffer buf
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (let ((lines '()))
        (while (not (eobp))
          (push (split-string
                 (buffer-substring (point) (point-at-eol)) "|")
                lines)
          (beginning-of-line 2))
        (nreverse lines)))))
```

Then with your example text in a buffer named `temp`, `(buffer-to-list-of-lists "temp")` returns the value

```
(("always" "five" "words" "by" "line") 
 ("not" "always" "the" "same" "words")
 ("sometimes" "no" "lines" "at" "all")
 ("but" "only" "five" "no" "more/less"))
```

This will work on lines with any number of `|`-separated words, which may or may not be better for your application. Change `buffer-substring` to `buffer-substring-no-properties` if you don't want the strings in your list-of-lists to include the font information and other properties they had in the original buffer.

Once you get this working as you'd like, you'll also need to change your example usage `(list-length '(lines))` to `(list-length lines)`. In its current form you're asking for the length of a constant one-element list containing only the symbol `lines`.

Comment: I had to put on sun glasses to read your "sur-mesure" answer. It's full of useful info, thank you very much dude, you are a gentleman and a scholar :)

Comment: @PhilippeCM ... and I had to open a French dictionary to find out what "sur-mesure" meant ;-) Glad it was helpful!

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume that variable `text` contains the content of your buffer as string, per [Jon O answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9874460/596361). Then use [`dash.el`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el) list API and [`s.el`](https://github.com/magnars/s.el) API functions:

```
(--map (s-split "|" it) (s-lines text))
```

[`--map`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-map-fn-list) is an [anaphoric version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphoric_macro) of `-map`, it exposes a temporary variable `it`, so that you don't have to pass an anonymous function. [`s-split`](https://github.com/magnars/s.el#s-split-separator-s-optional-omit-nulls) is a simple wrapper around `split-string`, [`s-lines`](https://github.com/magnars/s.el#s-split-separator-s-optional-omit-nulls) divides a string by newlines.

Answer (score 2):

Here' s a simple regexp based parser which may be useful as a start to achieve what you want:

```
(let (lines)
  (beginning-of-line)  
  (while (not (eobp))
    (push
     (if (looking-at "\\([^|\n]+\\)|\\([^|\n]+\\)|\\([^|\n]+\\)|\\([^|\n]+\\)|\\([^|\n]+\\)")
         (list (match-string-no-properties 1)
               (match-string-no-properties 2)
               (match-string-no-properties 3)
               (match-string-no-properties 4)
               (match-string-no-properties 5))    
       'no-match)
     lines)
    (forward-line 1))

  (setq lines (nreverse lines))

  (print lines))
```